# NLog internal log not working with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

I have a problem with NLog for logging its internal logs with this configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  throwExceptions="true"
  internalLogFile="${basedir}/App_Data/NLog.log"
  internalLogLevel="Trace">

   <targets>
      <target name="debug"
              xsi:type="File" 
              fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Site.log" />
   </targets>

   <rules>
      <logger name="*"
              writeTo="debug" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

The target "debug" is working well, but the internalLogFile is only working if I set it for exemple to "D:/NLog.log".

Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Note; the default path is where ever IISExpress is installed.  If you specify: InternalLogFile="nLogError.txt".  Then (at least on my PC) it will try and write to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\nlogExceptions.txt". Which can have permission problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use layout renderers ${...} in the internalLogFile property. They are for a target's layout only:

```
<target layout="${...}" />
```

Try to use relative path like "..\App_Data\NLog.log"

**Update** NLog 4.6 enables some [simple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65029948/193178).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Relative path are not working, it seems that it needs absolute path.

Comment: you are wrong..i am using ${} in internal logging and it works fine!! @Swell u can use ${..} in internal log file

Comment: @Neel Well, it might have changed after 2 years :) Could you show your NLog.config?

Comment: internalLogFile="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/Logs/Nlog/${shortdate}/Nlog-Internal.log"

Comment: yes @justips that is possible may be this has been expanded in 2 years

Comment: Very good comment from a NLog collaborator on why this is not a good idea [internalLogFile: NLog variables](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/581#issuecomment-74923718)

Comment: for the record the comment mentioned was " 304NotModified commented on 18 Feb 2015 | As answered at Stackoverflow: this isn't possible and also unwanted. The internal logfile should be as stable as possible (a so no fancy features). Also I think thank the internal log should only be used in rare cases."

Answer (score 5):

The `internalLogFile` attribute needs to be set to an absolute path and the executing assembly needs to have permission to write to that absolute path.

The following worked for me.

1. Create a folder somewhere - e.g. the route of your `c:` drive, e.g. `c:\logs`
2. Edit the permissions of this folder and give full control to everyone
3. Set your nlog config: `internalLogFile="C:\logs\nlog.txt"`

Remember to clean up after yourself and not leave a directory with those sorts of permissions on

Comment: Thx for the tip. That worked for me. It appears that .NET Framework requires an absolute path, but ASP.NET Core allows for relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

NLog ver. 4.6 add support for environment-variables like %appdata% or %HOME%, and using these basic layouts in `internalLogFile=`:

- ${currentdir}
- ${basedir}
- ${tempdir}

NLog ver. 4.7 also adds this:

- ${processdir}

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Answer (score 0):

from [this link](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging) I think the path is absolute